# How to change the color ok some pixels in an image in python using skimage?

Tags: python, image, colors, pixel, scikit-image

I am trying to change the color of the pixels that are not at position (0, 12, 24, 34, 44, ...). So I want to keep the color of the pixels at (0, 12, 24, 34, 44, ...) as it is and change the other pixels to white.
I tried this code:

```
import skimage.io as io

#I did a copy of the image to avoid making changes on the original image. The new image is called hidden.
hiddenImage = io.imread("mountain.png")  
io.imsave('hidden.jpg', hiddenImage )
hiddenImage = io.imread('hidden.jpg')
print(hiddenImage.shape)

  
lst=hiddenImage.tolist()

           
count = 0

## No error but not working
w=hiddenImage.shape[0]
h=hiddenImage.shape[1]


i=range (0, (w*h), 11) 
for row in range(w):
    for col in range(h):
        if count in i:
            pass
        else:
            hiddenImage[row, col] == [0,0,0]
        count += 1
#########Those are my other tries     
        #if count %11 ==1:
         #   hiddenImage[row, col] == [0,0,0]
        #count += 1
#########
        #if lst[row][col] %11==1:
         #   hiddenImage[row, col] == [0,0,0]
#########         
        #if row%11==1:
         #   hiddenImage[row, col] == [0, 0, 0]
        #elif col%11==1:
         #   hiddenImage[row, col] == [0, 0, 0]
### To show the image after the changes. But the image is still the same as before.
io.imshow(hiddenImage)
io.show()
```

What can I do to make the code work? I am basically trying to get a hidden image from an image. The first pixel at row 0, col 0 from the image was replaced by the first pixel at row 0, col 0 from the hidden image. And the pixel #12 (row 0, col 11) of the image was replaced by row 0, col 1 from the hidden image.